# Ecommerce data using Google Analytics/Google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to setup ecommerce data for a particular set of products. I have a store and it contains products from different vendors. I would like to enable particular vendors ecommerce data. My goal is, the vendor can see only his ecommerce data but not others product information. Is this possible using google analytic OR google tag manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Google Tag Manager in place it would be possible that load different GA profiles depending on a vendor ID, while also having an overall GA account for your own benefit. That way you can give each vendor it's own GA profile.

This does require that you are able to pass the vendor ID to Google Tag Manager from your ecommerce platform. Within Google Tag Manager you then setup up the necessary rules.

Comment: HI Marcel,Thank you for your answer. I would like to  clarify my question. We dont have any Vendor id. Our plan is to give authorization on this particular ecommerce data to my vendors email id. So when he login google analytics using his email, he would be able to see only his own ecommerce data,no other data of other vendors.Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Okay, but you would know which pages/data you want To show to which vendor? You need some way to distinct the data. If you can expose that to Google Tag Manager then my previous answer is still valid